# iPhone change local image resource to hosted URL's

Tags: iphone, ios, image, url, mobile

I'm using the following drop in, https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mkmovingblockanimation in my iOS Project, however i would like to load the images from a URL Array rather than the local resources. I've attached below the snippet that i think requires amending..

Any ideas?

```
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {

    self.slideImages = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        [self.slideImages addObject:[self imageWithBorderFromImage:[[CacheManager sharedInstance] imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png", i]]]];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        UIImage* img = [self.slideImages objectAtIndex:arc4random() % [self.slideImages count]];
        int size = frame.size.width;

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size - 6, size - 6);


        imageView.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, i * self.frame.size.height/8);

        [self addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release];
    }

}
return self;
```

Answer (score 2):

So first of all you should create a method/class that downloads the images from internet async so that your UI won't freeze. After you downloaded all the images call a method that loads the images in your container.

For async image download you can check [AFNetworking (AFImageRequestOperation)](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFImageRequestOperation.h). You should also check the [GCD](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/) for more details on threading and how you can switch from a background thread to the UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SDWebImage for downloading the images from url. Checkout below link

[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)